# Induction extended to ordered pairs: Application of the First Principle of Finite Induction to proving Bertrand’s Ballot Theorem.

Tags: probability, induction, well-orders

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531444/math-olympiad-question-probability-of-being-ahead-in-voting), the comments stated the existence of [Bertrand’s Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). In reading the article, I found a [peculiar application of proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Proof_by_induction). The text is as follows:

> - We loosen the condition $p>q$ to ${\displaystyle p\geq q}$. Clearly, the theorem is correct when
>   $p=q$, since in this case the first candidate will not be strictly ahead after all the votes have been counted (so the probability is 0). (**Comment: Base Case**)
> - Clearly the theorem is true if $p > 0$ and $q = 0$ when the probability is 1, given that the first candidate receives all the votes; it is also true when $p = q > 0$ as we have just seen.(**Comment: Base Case**)
> - (**Comment: Induction Hypothesis**) Assume it is true both when $p = a − 1$ and $q = b$, and when $p = a$ and $q = b − 1$, with $a > b > 0$. (We don't need to consider the case $a=b$ here, since we have already disposed of it before.)(**Comment: Induction Step**) Then considering the case with $p = a$ and $q = b$, the last vote counted is either for the first candidate with probability $\dfrac{a}{(a + b)}$, or for the second with probability $\dfrac{b}{(a + b)}$. So the probability of the first being ahead throughout the count to the penultimate vote counted (and also after the final vote) is:$$\dfrac{a}{a+b}\frac{(a-1)-b}{a+b-1}+ \dfrac{b}{a+b}\frac{a-(b-1)}{a+b-1} =\frac{a-b}{a+b}.$$
>   And so it is true for all $p$ and $q$ with $p > q > 0$.

I want to understand how the First Principle of Finite Induction can be applied rigorously here.

The First Principle of Finite Induction states that

> Let S be a set of positive integers with the following properties: 
> (i) The integer $1$ belongs to S,
> (ii) Whenever the integer $k$ is in S, the next integer $k+1$ must also be in S. 
> Then S is the set of all positive integers.

But here the statement seems to be as such (at least this is what I formulated/interpreted):

> Define set S such that if
>
> - $(a,0)\in S$ and $(0,a)\in S$
> - Whenever $(a,b-1)\in S$ and $(a-1,b)\in S$ it so happens that $(a,b)\in S$ $\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$
>
> > Then $S= \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

In order to prove this, I tried to formulate an analogous version of the Well-Ordering Principle, but failed, because it (almost obviously) doesn’t seem to exist for sets of ordered pairs.

**How to apply the First Principle of Finite Induction on the above mentioned proof**? Otherwise it is not exactly intuitive to me to apply induction to ordered pairs like this.

Comment: Let me know if you have any confusions regarding my answer!

Comment: **Note for readers**: With the help of @Shinrin-Yoku ‘s answer, I have written a self-answer which I intend to accept tomorrow. Any answers shedding even deeper insight, as well as any comments to improve my answer, are extremely welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll write a proof on the lines of the standard proof of the First Principle of Finite Induction:

The [Lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Cartesian_products) of a Cartesian product $A\times B$ of two sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as :

> If $a, a’\in A$ and $b, b’\in B$, then $$(a,b)\leq (a’,b’)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad a<a’ \quad\text{or}\quad (a=a’ \ \text{and}\ b\leq b’)$$

Consider the set $S$ such that it satisfies the given criteria. Consider the set $T$ such that it is the set of all the elements of $\mathbb N^2$ which are not in $S$, i.e., $T=\mathbb N^2\setminus S$. **Assume $T$ to be non-empty.**

Under the lexicographical ordering of $T$, consider $(a,b)$ to be the least element of $T$. Then, $a,b≠0$ because $(a,0)\in S$ and $(0,a)\in S$ $\forall a\in \mathbb N$ as per the hypothesis.

Now, by the minimal nature of $(a,b)$, along with the fact that $(a-1, b)<(a,b)$ and $(a,b-1)<(a,b)$ by the definition of the lexicographic order, $(a,b-1)$ and $(a-1,b)$ do not belong to $T$; consequently, they belong to the set $S$.

But by the hypothesis, $(a,b)$ must belong to $S$, which is a contradiction. Thus, our assumption is wrong and $T$ is empty. Thus, $S=\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

Hence proved. Q.E.D.$\qquad\blacksquare$

---

P.S. What I learnt from this was the lexicographical ordering for a Cartesian Product.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, then you can indeed prove that. Going for a contradiction, take the least pair under the lexographical ordering belonging to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ but not in $S$, both the coordinates $a,b$ of such a pair must be non-zero but then both $(a-1,b)$ and $(a,b-1)$ must be in $S$, a contradiction, hence no least pair exists which means that the intersection between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could you please explain “lexicographical order”? From what I read, it is based on only one coordinate of the two. So how did you apply it?

Comment: It is based on both coordinates. What if the first coordinates are equal? @insipidintegrator